# Finding a list of articles and pages with a high number of +1s

Tags: google-plus-1

I want to read the articles and webpages which are highly voted by readers around the world using Google's +1.

By voted I mean the articles which have the maximum count of +1s, or at least a very high count.

Is there a way to find out about these articles? Or is there any website that has a list of these articles?

Comment: I just found one website that is close: www.socialstatistics.com

Answer (score 1):

I have not found anything like that yet. The main reason will probably be that +1'ed links are shared among your friends. So unless you are friends with everyone, there is no way to tell what links got the most +1's (unless Google decides to start sharing that information).

Comment: From what I can tell, there are two different aspects of +1: the private ("eisb has +1'd this article") that will share among my friends, and the public ("this article has 1204 +1's") aspect of it, which will include my +1 but will not attach my name to it for people who are not my friends.

Look on any article with a +1 badge and you'll be able to see how many people have +1'd it.

Comment: Forgot that, you're right. So it boils down to either Google sharing that info, or somebody parsing articles for the +1 count.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Google Reader, you can try the [Explore link](http://support.google.com/reader/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=164681) that is above your own subscriptions.

> In the left-hand Explore section, you'll find Recommended items and
>   Recommended sources. We use algorithms to find fresh and rising
>   images, videos and pages from anywhere on the internet to generate the
>   Popular items, and then rank them in the order we think you'll like
>   them.

The articles that [Google recommends](http://googlereader.blogspot.com/2009/10/reading-gets-personal-with-popular.html) generally have a high number of +1s

> Your recommendations list is automatically generated - it takes into
>   account your existing feed subscriptions. Aggregated across many
>   users, this information can indicate which feeds are popular among
>   people with similar interests

Answer (score 0):

Here is a really cool site that does what your looking for and much more: http://www.gplusdata.com/leaderboard/pages/growth

Comment: The site is good for browsing Google+ users. I'm not sure it lists down +1's across internet.